# No additional dialog for my steward, can't buy Lumber in Lumber Mills

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

My hearthfire DLC is somehow messed up. I bought Windstad Manor normally, and once I went there, there's no additional quest. If I remember correctly there should be a series of quest to guide me through hearthfire content. I can build the house just fine, but I can't buy any Lumber in lumber mills. I can hire my housecarl as steward, but there's no additional dialog for my housecarl eventhough I hired her as steward. (e.g. I can't tell her to buy lumber)

I have HearthFire - Windstad Manor - Fortified and Upgradable (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/35079/?) mod installed. I am not sure if it's causing the problem. I tried to de-activate it through NMM, but nothing changed.

Currently I'm trying to find a way to reset everything related to hearthfire DLC, or try to fix this problem, can someone help me a little bit.

Comment: Have you already built a house before on that current save?

Comment: Read this after the answer. **As for your mod, try two fresh restarts quickly, become thane and try getting the quests to activate *with* and *without* the mod.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Starting the Quest

After watching [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vj128OxtnY) video on *how* to start the Hearthfire house quest, you should get a clear idea on what to do.

If this video is deleted, you don't understand it or don't want to watch it, here are some excerpts from it.

- A courier should come and give you a notice to buy a house. **(Citation needed?)**
- If you already are the ***Thane*** of either Falkreath, Dawnstar or Morthal, the Courier will **not** appear, and you can simply go to the Jarl and ask for a house. (Which you will need to buy)
- After purchasing your house, some Miscellaneous quests should pop up to guide you through house production.

Also a (probably) unreliable, but ***possible*** reason why it's not starting, can be found [**here**](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2961665) (with a fix), but **also** shown below:

> Finally solved.
>
> I've been going through my quest log completing all the quests. I was aware that I needed to complete any quests involving "radiant" quests but after finishing this already it didn't seem to do anything.
>
> So I continued on and came across one I could not complete. Or even click on anymore. It's the one called Collect Bounty from Skald. It wouldn't complete for some reason.
>
> So I tried several console commands:
>
> `setObjectiveCompleted BQ03 101 1`
>
> Setting the stage to different parts:
>
> `resetquest BQ03`
>
> Shortly after doing this I was greeted by a courier who dumped 3 letters on me. Orphans and visit Falkreath for purchasing were in there. yay!

By **themoon**.

---

## Obtaining Wood/Lumber

Ok. There are a couple of ways to go about this.

First of all, these are all the wood/lumber mills in Skyrim, and with their respective owners:

> <kbd>Owner</kbd> - <kbd>Location</kbd> - <kbd>Quest</kbd>
>
> <kbd>Aeri</kbd> - <kbd>Anga's Mill in The Pale</kbd> - <kbd>Chop Wood or Delivery</kbd>
>   <kbd>Bolund</kbd> - <kbd>The wood mill on the northeast side of Falkreath</kbd>
>   <kbd>Gilfre</kbd> - <kbd>Mixwater Mill in Eastmarch</kbd> - <kbd>Chop Wood</kbd>
>   <kbd>Grosta</kbd> - <kbd>Heartwood Mill in The Rift</kbd> - <kbd>Chop Wood or "Flight or Fight"</kbd>
>   <kbd>Hert</kbd> - <kbd>Half-Moon Mill in Falkreath Hold</kbd> - <kbd>Chop Wood</kbd>
>   <kbd>Hod</kbd> - <kbd>The wood mill on the southwest side of Riverwood</kbd> - <kbd>Chop Wood</kbd>
>   <kbd>Kharag gro-Shurkul</kbd> - <kbd>Solitude Sawmill in Haafingar</kbd>
>   <kbd>Thonnir</kbd> - <kbd>The wood mill on the north side of Morthal</kbd> - <kbd>Laid to Rest</kbd>

### Cutting your own

So, you can goto any of the above mills, and if your relationship with the mill owner is good enough, you may come and go as you please.

You can walk up to the mill, going through the *really* slow animation of your character moving wood/lumber onto the saw, and then obtain some free wood/lumber for your home!

To gain "reputation" with the mill owner, follow the below excerpt.

Excerpt from [**here**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sawn_Log#Sawn_Logs):

> The following table **(the one above)** lists lumber mill owners who will sell sawn logs via dialogue.
>
> The 'Quest' column indicates guaranteed quests for the lumber merchant in that row which will raise their disposition enough to allow you to cut your own logs for free.
>
> You must receive permission via dialogue before activating the mill will yield results.
>   If an entry in the column is blank, there are no guaranteed quests which raise that specific lumber merchant's disposition.
>
> However, there are other ways to raise an NPC's disposition, such as certain radiant quests for which the target can be almost any NPC in the game (e.g., Rescue Mission).
>
> While some of these quests can still raise a lumber merchant's disposition enough for them to allow you to cut your own lumber for free, they are not listed here because you are not guaranteed to receive a specific NPC as a target for that quest.

### Buying it

There are two ways to **buy** wood/lumber.

**Via. Steward**

If you own a house, and have a steward who also lives there, you can ask him/her to buy wood/lumber for you indirectly, and it will appear outside immediately.

**Via. Yourself**

If all else fails, just walk up to the mill owner, and ask to buy some wood/lumber for 200 gold / per 20 logs.

**You *may* need to be in a friendly relationship to do so though. So check that you are. (Clarification needed)**

Comment: "After watching **this** video", are you missing a link?

Comment: @pinckerman Ah! Thanks for pointing that out. I appreciate it.

Comment: @FinnRayment that video you want us to see was unapropriate and what I mean is if you click on it.